# How to keep original entries for multiple time series and use interpolation to fill NaN values for different time measurements?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I would like to find for each ID, earliest measurement time before 00:00:00 and latest measurement time after 00:00:00. So that I can choose maximum overlapping start and ending time. Here is the sample data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import random

# Create a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': pd.date_range(start='2022-01-01', end='2022-01-01 23:59', freq='4H')})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': pd.date_range(start='2022-01-01', end='2022-01-01 23:59', freq='5H')})

df['value']= [random.randrange(10, 19) for n in range(len(df))]
df['ID']= [random.randrange(1, 4) for n in range(len(df))]

df2['value']= [random.randrange(10, 19) for n in range(len(df2))]
df2['ID']= [random.randrange(1, 4) for n in range(len(df2))]

merged_df = df.merge(df2,  how='outer', on =['timestamp'])
# Pivot the dataframe to create a new dataframe with all time measurements for each ID
#merged_df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='value', index=['ID', 'timestamp'], aggfunc='sum')

# Reset the index to create a regular dataframe
merged_df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)

# sort by time
merged_df.sort_values(by=['timestamp'],inplace=True)

# Print the result
print(merged_df)
```

I have two different time series whose measurements are made for every 20 minutes and other for every 15 minutes.

**My expectation** is to keep original measurements of VALUE_1 column in merged dataframe. Besides, I would like to interpolate values for recording times that does not have VALUE_1 entry. Since df1 has measurements for every 20 minutes, and df2 has for each 15 minutes. df1 does not have any value of VALUE_1 column for TIME 00:15:00, 00:30:00,or 00:45:00 and so on. df2 is measured for every 15 minutes, so it does not have value of VALUE_1 for 00:20:00,00:40:00, and so on. How can I fill and interpolate those time points while keeping the original measurements?

**Minimal Example:** Consider I have such a dataframe with different time intervals.

| ID | VALUE1 | TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 50 | 00:04:00 |
| 25 | 80 | 00:04:30 |
| 25 | 100 | 00:05:00 |
| 25 | 100 | 00:05:30 |
| 25 | 100 | 00:06:00 |
| 18 | 45 | 00:04:02 |
| 18 | 33 | 00:04:22 |
| 18 | 75 | 00:04:42 |
| 18 | 57 | 00:05:02 |
| 18 | 99 | 00:05:22 |

**Expected Output:**

| ID | VALUE1 | TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 50 | 00:04:00 |
| 25 | Interpolated VALUE=maybe (50+80)/2 | 00:04:02 |
| 25 | Interpolated VALUE | 00:04:22 |
| 25 | 80 | 00:04:30 |
| 25 | Interpolated VALUE | 00:04:42 |
| 25 | 100 | 00:05:00 |
| 25 | Interpolated VALUE | 00:05:02 |
| 25 | Interpolated VALUE | 00:05:22 |
| 25 | 100 | 00:05:30 |
| 25 | 100 | 00:06:00 |
| 18 | Interpolated VALUE=45 maybe repetition of closest | 00:04:00 |
| 18 | 45 | 00:04:02 |
| 18 | 33 | 00:04:22 |
| 18 | some Interpolated VALUE | 00:04:30 |
| 18 | 75 | 00:04:42 |
| 18 | some Interpolated VALUE | 00:04:30 |
| 18 | 57 | 00:05:02 |
| 18 | 99 | 00:05:22 |
| 18 | some Interpolated VALUE | 00:05:00 |
| 18 | some Interpolated VALUE | 00:05:30 |
| 18 | some Interpolated VALUE | 00:06:00 |

**EDIT 1:** If I had only two separate time series, I could merge them on DATE_TIME or TIME (using outer merge), so that I can keep original time recording and the recording from other time series. Then, I could just interpolate it. Now, I am trying to figure out how to do it for multiple time series.

Comment: Your example is reproducible, but **definitely not minimal**! Please give a very simple example (e.g. 3 rows and 1 or 2 columns for each `df`) with only the minimum number of columns necessary to illustrate what you are stuck on. And please provide the desired output.

Comment: @PierreD I just edited my question. Is it any better now?

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I still have no idea what you are trying to do. Please start with a simple example for `df1` and `df2`, and then show the expected output. If `df1` has times at 0, 15, 30, 60, ... and `df2` at 0, 20, 40, 60, ..., then merging the two will have values at all times 0, 15, 20, 30, 40, 45, 60. Some will have just one value (from one of the `df`s), but multiples of 60 (round minutes) will have two. A **simple example** (5 rows in each `df`) and the exact desired result would explain what you want.

Comment: Also, please format data so it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, it is hard to guess what the expected output would be. But here are some pointers on how to bring both DataFrames on a common DateTime index, and also how to interpolate the numeric columns:

```py
# set DATE_TIME as index and keep only numeric columns
a = df.set_index('DATE_TIME').select_dtypes(include=[np.number])
b = df2.set_index('DATE_TIME').select_dtypes(include=[np.number])

# take the union of both indexes
ix = a.index.union(b.index)

# reindex and interpolate
a = a.reindex(ix).interpolate()
b = b.reindex(ix).interpolate()
```

Now both `a` and `b` have the same (irregular) time index. They have kept their initial measurements, and the missing values have been filled by linear interpolation. For example, for `a`:

```py
>>> a
                      ID  VALUE1  VALUE2  VALUE3  VALUE4  MODEL  SOLD  INSPECTION
DATE_TIME                                                                        
2022-11-01 00:00:00  3.0   132.0    54.0    81.0    47.0    2.0   1.0         1.0
2022-11-01 00:15:00  2.5   128.5    52.5    89.5    42.5    1.5   0.5         1.0
2022-11-01 00:20:00  2.0   125.0    51.0    98.0    38.0    1.0   0.0         1.0
...                  ...     ...     ...     ...     ...    ...   ...         ...
2022-11-01 23:30:00  2.5   120.5    50.5    96.0    34.0    1.5   0.0         1.0
2022-11-01 23:40:00  3.0   129.0    50.0    93.0    38.0    2.0   0.0         1.0
2022-11-01 23:45:00  3.0   129.0    50.0    93.0    38.0    2.0   0.0         1.0
```

Comment: Since I have ID column in original data also in string format, unfortunately this method does not work

Comment: Hence my comment on providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result.

Comment: I created the example table and expected output